# Is there a difference between <> and != in python?

Tags: python, syntax

I am wondering if <> and != do the exact same evaluation or one is somehow different from the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/comparisons.html:

> <> and != are alternate spellings for the same operator.
>   != is the preferred spelling; <> is obsolescent.

Comment: Furthermore, it's **removed** in 3.0 and later.